# Does Flutter 3 support Webview on Desktop?

Tags: flutter, webview, multiplatform

[Flutter 3](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-announces-flutter-3/) was released recently with Desktop platform support for Windows, Linux and macOS.

Can Flutter developers clarify if Flutter 3 also supports *Webview* on Windows, Linux and macOS? [Flutter documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) seems to suggest *Webview* support exists only for Android and ios.

Would appreciate some insights as I have a project that requires *Webview*, and if Flutter 3 supports it on all platforms it would make my work a lot easier. (I am asking here before trying out Flutter myself as I am completely unfamiliar with Flutter, and need to know about *Webview* status before I invest my time to learn Flutter).

(**Note**: Please do not go on a tangent and focus on "why webview" or whether it is apt etc. as I have no choice in the matter - it's one of the stated requirement of the project and I cannot change it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No Flutter 3 Does not support Webview on Desktop, however you can use a package -
https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_webview_window

Comment: when I run the code, two windows lunched, one is empty, and one contains the webview, do you have a solution for this problem please ?